# I am having toruble installing the puppeteer library

Tags: node.js, npm, puppeteer

I am trying to build a simple web scraper and the first thing I have to do is install the puppeteer library. So I run the commands (I am on the latest linux Mint): 
`sudo npm init -y` and `sudo npm i puppeteer` but I get these errors:

```
▌ ╢░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
WARN engine puppeteer@3.0.2: wanted: {"node":">=10.18.1"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"3.5.2"})
loadDep:ws → request      ▄ ╢███████████████████████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟

> puppeteer@3.0.2 install /home/USER/Documents/anna/file/node_modules/puppeteer
> node install.js

(node:11081) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function
    at promisify (internal/util.js:209:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/USER/Documents/anna/file/node_modules/extract-zip/index.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/USER/Documents/anna/file/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/BrowserFetcher.js:25:17)
(node:11081) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11081) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
file@1.0.0 /home/USER/Documents/anna/file
└── puppeteer@3.0.2  extraneous

npm WARN ws@7.2.5 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ws@7.2.5 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN file@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN file@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to upgrade your Node.js version.  The warning in the output:

```
WARN engine puppeteer@3.0.2: wanted: {"node":">=10.18.1"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"3.5.2"})
```

indicates you're running Node 8.10 and Puppeteer expects Node >= 10.18.1.