# Not able to install playwright@1.0.2

Tags: node.js, npm, playwright

Hi I am trying to install playwright.

Facing this issue

```
$ npm i playwright

> playwright@1.0.2 install /Users/chandanj/fr/play-wright-play/node_modules/playwright
> node install.js

internal/util.js:214
    throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'original', 'function');
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "original" argument must be of type function
    at promisify (internal/util.js:214:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/chandanj/fr/play-wright-play/node_modules/extract-zip/index.js:11:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/chandanj/fr/play-wright-play/node_modules/playwright-core/lib/install/browserFetcher.js:19:17)
npm WARN play-wright@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN play-wright@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! playwright@1.0.2 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the playwright@1.0.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Not able to figure out what is causing the issue.
Tried with node versions 12.16.3 and 10.20.1

Comment: I know you mentioned your node versions. But it seems that the issue with `extract-zip` is related to the node version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61770784/typeerror-err-invalid-arg-type-the-original-argument-must-be-of-type-functi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61524375/i-am-having-toruble-installing-the-puppeteer-library

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I was able to get through the previous error and landed on another 503 google chrome not available.